# Exponential Algorithm for a Slider Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, math

This is a question relating to a slider control in Objective-C but I guess it's a question for any Math bods out there...

I have 2 values:

min = 20;
max = 1000;

I also have another value:

inc = 10;

As the user slides the slider control I want to display an output value between min and max over 10 evenly distributed snap points.

Each snap point should output a value of:

min + x*inc;

x is going to increase the higher the snap point is on the slider.

I want the output to gradually exponentially increase between min and max whereby the increments get larger the near the user gets to the top of the slider.

Eg, something like: 20, 30, 50, 100, 180, 280, 420, 600, 800, 1000

What's the required maths to achieve this and evenly distribute exponentially increasing increments between min and max?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you should take the log, interpolate linearly and go back to exponential scale:

```
i-th point among n = exp(log(min) + (i/n)*(log(max)-log(min)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make valueChange of your UISlider point to this function, it works. Replace M_E by any float number if you want to change the shape of your exponential values. Display the final exponential value

```
-(IBAction)changeSliderExponentially:(id)sender{

UISlider * slider = (UISlider *)sender;
CGFloat inc = 10.0f;

int discreteValue = round(slider.value * inc);
CGFloat finalValue = discreteValue/inc;
[slider setValue:finalValue];

int min = 20.0f;
int max = 1000.0f;

double exponentialValue = (max - min)*(pow(M_E,finalValue) - pow(M_E,-finalValue))/(pow(M_E,1.0f) - pow(M_E,-1.0f)) + min;
NSLog(@"%f",exponentialValue);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Here's @hivert 's answer updated for Swift 4 and with the OPs example numbers:

```
let steps = 10
let min: Double = 25
let max: Double = 1000

for i in 0...steps-1 {
  let value = exp(log(min) + (Double(i) / Double(steps-1)) * (log(max) - log(min)))
  print("step: \(i + 1), value: \(round(value))")
}
```

Output:

```
step: 1, value: 25.0
step: 2, value: 38.0
step: 3, value: 57.0
step: 4, value: 85.0
step: 5, value: 129.0
step: 6, value: 194.0
step: 7, value: 292.0
step: 8, value: 441.0
step: 9, value: 664.0
step: 10, value: 1000.0
```